Double Execution of Firebase Function in Emulator Environment
I've noticed that when running in the Firebase emulator environment, modifying the function and making a single GET request for the first time causes the function to execute twice:
@https_fn.on_request(
    cors=options.CorsOptions(
        cors_origins=["*"],
        cors_methods=["GET"],
    )
)
def delete(req: https_fn.Request) -> https_fn.Response:
    print(f"Request Method: {req.method}")
    print(f"Request Headers: {dict(req.headers)}")

Here’s the log output:
>  Request Method: GET
>  Request Headers: {'Host': '127.0.0.1:8739', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Function-Execution-Id': '3rNmdjC5Ny1v'}
i  functions: Beginning execution of "us-central1-delete"
>  Request Method: GET
>  Request Headers: {'Host': '127.0.0.1:5001', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:132.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/132.0', 'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8', 'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br, zstd', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1', 'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document', 'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate', 'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'none', 'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1', 'Priority': 'u=0, i', 'Function-Execution-Id': 'sTnlZgBK7dGx'}

It appears that the first request is not coming from my browser, suggesting the emulator might be performing some sort of warm-up or caching operation.
Has anyone else encountered this issue, and are there any solutions to prevent this double execution in the emulator?
Thanks!
